# Multivariable calculus calculating the surface integral under a vector field

Tags: calculus

Let S be the surface 
                    $S={{(x,y,z) :x^2+y^2+2(z-1)^2=6, z>0}}$
with outwards pointing unit normal. Let $F$ be the vector field

$$F(x,y,z)=(xz-y^3e^z,x^3cosz,xyze^{xy})$$

Calculate the surface integral

What i tried

The surface $$S={{(x,y,z) :x^2+y^2+2(z-1)^2=6, z>0}}$$ can be simplified to $$S={{(x,y,z) :x^2+y^2=4, z=0}}$$
But im unsure why is it done in this way and what is the physical interpretation of this.
For this problem, my first thought is to use Divergence theorem to solve it by converting it to a triple integral and then solving it. However, upon using the divergence theorem, I realize that it is not as simple as just simply plugging in the formula and then evulating the answer. I know that i must first visualize the surface $S$ in 3D and then considering the many surface as well as their flux and then adding or subtracting the flux whenever appropriate. And there are several surfaces to consider in this question. It is this that confuses me. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{{{x^2}}}{{{{\left( {\sqrt 2 } \right)}^2}}} + \frac{{{y^2}}}{{{{\left( {\sqrt 2 } \right)}^2}}} + {\left( {z - 1} \right)^2} = 3$

So it is an ellipsoid cut by the plane $z = 0$ from below with 2 semi-axis (those parallel to the $x,y$ plane) lengths $\sqrt 6 $ and one semi-axis length (the one parallel to the $z$ axis) $\sqrt 3 $ with the center $\left( {0,0,1} \right)$.

Note that the part of the ellipsoid above $x,y$ plane has the plane $x,y$ cut out, so the boundary of the surface is obtained by putting $z = 0$ which gives us the curve ${x^2} + {y^2} + 2 = 6 \Leftrightarrow {x^2} + {y^2} = 4$, which is a circle of radius 2 around origin.

The surface integral is $\int_S {\left( {F \cdot n} \right)dS} $, we want to find a vector field $H$ such that its curl $\nabla  \times H$ is equal to $F$, since then we'd have $\int_S {\left( {F \cdot n} \right)dS}  = \int_S {\left( {\left( {\nabla  \times H} \right) \cdot n} \right)dS}  = \int_{\partial S} {Hd\ell } $, with $H = \left( {P,Q,R} \right)$. This gives us a system of partial differential equations:

$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \frac{{\partial R}}{{\partial y}} - \frac{{\partial Q}}{{\partial z}} = xz - {y^3}{e^z} \\
  \frac{{\partial P}}{{\partial z}} - \frac{{\partial R}}{{\partial x}} = {x^3}\cos z \\
  \frac{{\partial Q}}{{\partial x}} - \frac{{\partial P}}{{\partial y}} = xyz{e^{xy}} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

After obtaining $P,Q$, the integral becomes $\int_{\partial S} {Pdx + Qdy} $., where $\partial S = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right):{x^2} + {y^2} = 4} \right\}$

Comment: Can i use the divergence theorem to solve it by changing it to a triple integral?

Comment: The surface integral should be a double integral.

Comment: Mathematicians don't bother with writing number of integrals equal to the number of dimensions, since we generally work with $n$-dimensional spaces. Imagine how many integral signs you'd have to write :)

Comment: I think the idea is to change it to a curve integral